# Making input file required

Tags: javascript, html, forms, laravel

I intend to cause the field to be required but the traditional way is not working.
Some help? I'm using the validity parsley

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'backend/portfolio', 'id' => 'form', 'name' => 'InserirPortfolio', 'role' => 'form', 'files'=> true, 'class' => 'form-signin', 'data-validate' => 'parsley'))!!}

{!! Form::label('imagens', 'Imagem', ['class' => 'label_perfil']) !!}
{!! Form::file('imagens[]', array('multiple'=>true),[
    'class'         => 'input-file',
    'data-required' => 'true'
]) !!}
```

How i see in my html

```
<input multiple="1" name="imagens[]" type="file">
```

One example as i have

```
{!! Form::textarea('descricao', null, [
    'class'                         => 'form-control input-md', 
    'style'                         => 'height: 100px; resize: none;', 
    'placeholder'                   => 'Descrição',
    'data-required'                 => 'true',
    'data-required-message'         => 'O campo Descrição é obrigatório',                                           
    'pattern'                       => '^[0-9A-Za-zãÃáÁàÀêÊéÉèÈíÍìÌôÔõÕóÓòÒúÚùÙûÛçÇ. ]*$',
    'data-pattern-message'          => 'Está algo errado',
    'data-minlength'                => '10',
    'data-minlength-message'        => 'A descrição tem de ter 10 caracteres obrigatórios',
    'data-maxlength'                => '200',
    'data-maxlength-message'        => 'A descrição não pode conter mais de 200 caracteres',                                        

]) !!}
```

Comment: From the documentation it lookes like you should use `data-parsley-requiredz instead of `data-required` (but @EzequiasDinella's suggestion to use a simple `required` attribute should work as well) . Also how are you initialising parsley? Are you sure your client side setup is correct? Do other fields get validated correctyle? Please edit your question to include that information.

Comment: I edited the post and parsley works on all straight least in the input file

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
{!! Form::label('imagens', 'Imagem', ['class' => 'label_perfil']) !!}
{!! Form::file('imagens[]', array('multiple'=>true),[
    'class'         => 'input-file',
    'data-required' => 'true',
    'required' => 'required'
]) !!}
```

Comment: yes and nothing. I use the model modal of bootstrap and I need me soon the error